# Set font and size on ColumnText in iTextSharp

Tags: c#, .net, pdf, itext

I am adding to an existing pdf-template some text, image, and a html string.  I have managed to add the text and image, but when I add the html elements to the ColumnText I can not figure out how to set font and size on that particular ColumnText.

Is there any way to set font and size to the ColumnText?

```
const string oldFile = "c:\\template.pdf";
const string newFile = "c:\\brandNewFile.pdf";
const string lightFontFile = "c:\\HelveticaNeueLight.ttf";
const string boldFontFile = "c:\\HelveticaNeueBoldItalic.ttf";
const string thinlight = "c:\\HelveticaNeueThinItalic.ttf";
const string logo = "c:\\logo.png";

// open the reader
var reader = new PdfReader(oldFile);
Rectangle size = reader.GetPageSizeWithRotation(1);
var document = new Document(size);

// open the writer
var fs = new FileStream(newFile, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);
var writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, fs);
document.Open();

// the pdf content
PdfContentByte cb = writer.DirectContent;

// Very nice font and size
var veryNiceBaseFont = BaseFont.CreateFont(boldFontFile, BaseFont.CP1252, BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED);
cb.SetColorFill(new BaseColor(0x00, 0x57, 0x94)); // Certain BLUE RGB
cb.SetFontAndSize(veryNiceBaseFont, 11f);

// Add text
cb.BeginText();
text = "Here is an amazing text that I add on top of the template!";
cb.SetCharacterSpacing(0.8f);
cb.ShowTextAligned(PdfContentByte.ALIGN_LEFT, text, 79, 582, 0);
cb.EndText();

// Different font
var paragraphBaseFont = BaseFont.CreateFont(lightFontFile, BaseFont.CP1252, BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED);
cb.SetColorFill(BaseColor.BLACK); 
cb.SetFontAndSize(paragraphBaseFont, 12f);

// Add more text
cb.BeginText();
string text = "More text in different font";
cb.SetCharacterSpacing(0.8f);
cb.ShowTextAligned(PdfContentByte.ALIGN_LEFT, text, 79, 600, 0);
cb.EndText();

// Add the logo image
Image image = Image.FromFile(logo);
iTextSharp.text.Image pic = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(image, ImageFormat.Png);
if (pic.Height > pic.Width)
{
    //Maximum height is 800 pixels.
    float percentage = 0.0f;
    percentage = 110 / pic.Height;
    pic.ScalePercent(percentage * 100);
}
else
{
    //Maximum width is 600 pixels.
    float percentage = 0.0f;
    percentage = 80 / pic.Width;
    pic.ScalePercent(percentage * 100);
}
pic.SetAbsolutePosition(440, 575);
cb.AddImage(pic);

// Create the new page and add it to the pdf
PdfImportedPage page = writer.GetImportedPage(reader, 1);
cb.AddTemplate(page, 0, 0);

// create the html part of the document
string html =
    "<p>This is a paragraph. Derp derp derp derp !</p>" +
    "<p><strong><span style=\"color: #005794;\">With some style and such.</span></strong></p>" +
    "<p>DERP</p>" +
    "<p><span style=\"color: #ed1c24;\">DERP</span></p>" +
    "<p>DERP</p>";


var elements = XMLWorkerHelper.ParseToElementList(html, null);
var paragraph = new Paragraph();
paragraph.Font = new Font(iTextSharp.text.Font.FontFamily.HELVETICA, 10f); //not working!!!!
//TODO: I am confused, should I try to set font as above, or somehow set columntext?
foreach (var es in elements)
{
    paragraph.Add(es);
    paragraph.Add(Chunk.NEWLINE);
}
var ct = new ColumnText(cb);
ct.SetSimpleColumn(paragraph, 80, 460, 475, 0, 15, Element.ALIGN_LEFT);
ct.Go();

// close the streams and voilá the file should be changed :)
document.Close();
fs.Close();
writer.Close();
reader.Close();
```

Abbreviated code (I was asked to remove unecessary code in comments):

```
    // create the html part of the document
string html =
    "<p>This is a paragraph. Derp derp derp derp !</p>" +
    "<p><strong><span style=\"color: #005794;\">With some style and such.</span></strong></p>" +
    "<p>DERP</p>" +
    "<p><span style=\"color: #ed1c24;\">DERP</span></p>" +
    "<p>DERP</p>";


var elements = XMLWorkerHelper.ParseToElementList(html, null);
var paragraph = new Paragraph();
paragraph.Font = new Font(iTextSharp.text.Font.FontFamily.HELVETICA, 10f); //not working!!!!
//TODO: I am confused, should I try to set font as above, or somehow set columntext?
foreach (var es in elements)
{
    paragraph.Add(es);
    paragraph.Add(Chunk.NEWLINE);
}
var ct = new ColumnText(cb);
ct.SetSimpleColumn(paragraph, 80, 460, 475, 0, 15, Element.ALIGN_LEFT);
ct.Go();
```

Comment: Please remove all the unnecessary code from your example. It is very confusing to see you use `cb.BeginText();` and so on in a question about converting HTML to PDF. When you convert HTML to PDF, you set the font and size in your HTML.

Comment: I edited the question @BrunoLowagie, this is the part where I am having truble with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to change the BaseFont for the IElements, and therefore set any font and size I want (but also keep font-weight and color from the inline markup style).

Here is an example from the abbreviated code above:

```
string html =
    "<p>This is a paragraph. Derp derp derp derp !</p>" +
    "<p><strong><span style=\"color: #005794;\">With some style and such.</span></strong></p>" +
    "<p>DERP</p>" +
    "<p><span style=\"color: #ed1c24;\">DERP</span></p>" +
    "<p>DERP</p>";

var elements = XMLWorkerHelper.ParseToElementList(html, null);
var paragraph = new Paragraph();
foreach (var es in elements)
{
    // 
    var tempBase = BaseFont.CreateFont(lightFontFile, BaseFont.CP1252, BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED);
    var tempFont = new Font(tempBase, es.Chunks[0].Font.Size, es.Chunks[0].Font.Style, es.Chunks[0].Font.Color);
    foreach (var chunk in es.Chunks)
    {
        chunk.Font = tempFont;
    }
    paragraph.Add(es);
    paragraph.Add(Chunk.NEWLINE);
}
var ct = new ColumnText(cb);
ct.SetSimpleColumn(paragraph, 80, 460, 475, 0, 15, Element.ALIGN_LEFT);
ct.Go();
```